# How to specify directory for NDK_MODULE_PATH

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk

I am having a trouble with this simple task for last couple of hours.

I have ndk-modules directory in root of my Android project and I have following in my Android.mk of jni folder

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
NDK_MODULE_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../ndk-modules
...
$(call import-module,mymodule)
```

When I build the mk file, I got

```
Android NDK: /MyApp/jni/Android.mk: Cannot find module with tag 'mymodule' in import path    
Android NDK: Are you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly defined ?
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I specify the path correctly?

UPDATE:

The specification was right. I had a problem in mymodule directory. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

NDK_MODULE_PATH must be in your path. I wanted to specify it in my Android.mk file so I added this line before the import-module line:

```
$(call import-add-path,my_relative_path)
```

Comment: can u elebprate what do you mean by -add-path and my_relative_path

Comment: like this ```$(call import-add-path, /home/bluemix/tmp/android-ffmpeg-tutorial01-master/jni)
$(call import-module,ffmpeg-2.6.2/android/arm)```

Comment: check following implementation. Make much more sense https://github.com/julienr/protobuf-android

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I fixed it by realizing NDK searches for:

```
$NDK_MODULE_PATH/module_name/Android.mk
```

But my "module_name" is an Eclipse project where Android.mk is under:

```
$NDK_MODULE_PATH/module_name/jni/Android.mk
```

So NDK cannot find it. I fixed it by:

1. Move module_name/jni/* to "somewhere/module_name".
2. In Android.mk:

   ```
   $(call import-add-path, /path/to/somewhere)
   $(call import-module,module_name)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

$(call import-module,mymodule) will search $NDK_MODULE_PATH/mymodule, you may set path to top level of the project or create a folder named mymodule under ndk-modules

Comment: If your Android.mk is in prj/jni, then $LOCAL_PATH/.. should be the top.