# Setting the NDK_MODULE_PATH variable in Cygwin

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to create a module with the Android NDK, but I can't seem to get the build program to take the path variable. I have tried setting it as an environment variable in cygwin:

```
$ echo $NDK_MODULE_PATH
/cygdrive/c/dev/code/git/android_source
```

I also specify it within the Android.mk file:

```
#=================================== 
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
NDK_MODULE_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../code/git/android_source/
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := user
LOCAL_MODULE := libFilters
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := SkewFilter.cpp SkewFilter.h

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := -lz
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBS := libskia

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
#=================================== 

$(call import-module,libskia)
```

The end result is still this:

```
$ ndk-build
Android NDK: jni/Android.mk: Cannot find module with tag 'libskia' in import path
Android NDK: Are you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly defined ?
Android NDK: The following directories were searched:
Android NDK:
jni/Android.mk:17: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.
```

Anyone have any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

I found this question [How to specify directory for NDK_MODULE_PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549691/how-to-specify-directory-for-ndk-module-path) but it wasn't any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. This line in the Android.mk file needs to change from:

```
$(call import-module,libskia)
```

to

```
$(call import-module,external/skia)
```

It doesn't do a recursive search for the module so when calling import-module it needs the full path relative to your NDK_MODULE_PATH (NDK_MODULE_PATH + path_to_module).

The error message that ndk-build prints seems to be wrong since it doesn't list any paths in the NDK_MODULE_PATH variable, but they are there and it uses them.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. Neither adapting import-module nor adding the full path to NDK_MODULE_PATH made the error message go away. I suspect some annoying issue with slashes to be the cause.