# The meaning of "variable" with respect to configuring eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, windows-7-x64

Several times I have seen documentation that makes statements like "set the XXX variable to YYY", but I am not at all sure how/where these "variables" get set. Sometimes it looks like they may be old-style DOS environment variables (which I know how to set), but other times not.

So for example, looking at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549691/how-to-specify-directory-for-ndk-module-path), the accepted answer states "NDK_MODULE_PATH must be in your path" - would that mean the DOS-environment-path? Or some other path? And in [this document](https://code.google.com/p/android-ndk-profiler/wiki/Usage), it says "When you compile, you need to set the NDK_MODULE_PATH variable to the directory above...". What kind of "variable" is that? A DOS-environment variable? Some other kind? How/where would I set it?

**EDIT:** Just a thought - if I go to Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Build > Build Variables, I see I can add things there - do you think that's what was meant in the two examples?

Comment: Whats your operating system? Every os has environment variables. Here's a guide for Windows : http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: Just added windows 7 tag. But are you saying that in all cases the answer is old DOS style environment variables? In which case, I know how to set them already.

Comment: There is nothing 'old' in environment variables , but yes - they are the same and can be seen with the 'set' command in the windows console.

Comment: Oh, sorry , i didn't read the posts carefully. Those are variables in your .mk file (e.g. Android.mk). I dont remember if its generated, yor your should create it explicitly.